# Self contained Sikuli scripts

Tags: python, sikuli

I would like to pass on some sikuli automation to researchers; although they do not have much computer knowledge, nor they want to fiddle with the IDE or install anything, so I was wondering if I can wrap the whole thing in an executable.

Is this possible? And if so, how do you accomplish this? I am using python on OSX. I would like to make something that the researcher can double click and run; and collect their result; so no hassle for them, beside send me the output file with the results.

Comment: have a look at http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: Interesting! Is there an equivalent for OSX too?